# Refactoring many else if, else if, else if, etc. statements

Tags: c#, coding-style, refactoring, clean-code

I'm trying to parse readable data from PDFs and I keep ending up writing code like the following:

```
if (IsDob(line))
{
    dob = ParseDob(line);
}
else if (IsGender(line))
{
    gender = ParseGender(line);
}
...
...
...
else if (IsRefNumber(line))
{
    refNumber = ParseRefNumber(line);
}
else
{
    unknownLines.Add(line);
}
```

Then I use all this data to build up relevant objects, e.g. Customer using all of their personal data.

This tends to get kind of ugly when there's lots to parse.

I've split them up into functions like TryParsePersonalInfo(line), TryParseHistory(line) etc. But that feels like it's just moving the problem as I still have these endless else ifs everywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best approach - convert multiple conditional if -else in a more handy design](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/366803/best-approach-convert-multiple-conditional-if-else-in-a-more-handy-design)

Comment: I don't see how I could implement that here? Each line is essentially just a string with some metadata, and I need to check the structure of the string to figure out what it is. Each one also then has to be parsed differently.

Comment: For this particular problem, you may want to switch to a parser generator, which can generate the nasty code for you. Perhaps Antlr.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's what I would start with given the information you've provided.

Create an interface like so:

```
interface LineProcessor<E> {
  boolean Process(Record record, Line line); 
}
```

Let's assume Record is a propery bag for now.  Don't get hung up on this, I'm keeping it simple for demonstration purposes.

```
class Record {
  public Date dob { get; set; }
  public String gender { get; set; }
  public String refNumber { get; set; }
  // ...
}
```

Sorry if the syntax is not right for C#.  If you aren't sure what I'm getting at, I'll clarify.

Then create a list of instances of LineParser: one for type of line.  Then, you write a loop (python/pseudocode):

```
for line in pdf:
  obj = process(record, line)

def process(record, line):
  for handler in processors:
    if handler.process(record, line): return
  else:
    unknown.add(line)
```

Now the implementation of one of these might look like so:

```
class DobProcessor implements LineProcessor {
  boolean process(Record record, Line line) {
    if (IsDob(line)) {
      record.dob = ParseDob(line);
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  Date ParseDob(Line line) {
    //...
  }

  boolean IsDob(Line line) {
    //...
  }
}
```

This should make the code more manageable.  Instead of a large if statement, you will have a number of classes where each one is specific to a case.  This not only organizes the code, it means you can add or remove cases without touching any of the code around other cases.

One other thing is that now that the processes interface is down to a single method, you can actually start thinking of this as more of a function pointer/lambda so you can dispense with the interface if you so desire.

Comment: The one thing I would tweak is that for the particular implementation, the "parser" needs to change the state on an object. I probably would call it a handler and have handler.handle(line, object). Then the handle function can update object's dob, gender, refNumber, etc.

Comment: @ChrisG I'm not seeing that in the problem description.  Also, I thought names like 'handler' and 'manager' are typically discouraged since they don't really illuminate anything about what they do.  Full disclosure: I've named many a type ..Handler but looking back, I tend to agree that this is not a great name.

Comment: Thanks @JimmyJames. While this does look tidier, I think I'd just be moving a lot of the code to handling what the parser loop returns? Each parse function is returning a different (but sometimes the same) object type based on what was parsed. Getting these back out and into the local variables is again going to look untidy, no?

Comment: @LeviH It's hard to tell exactly what you want to do with the results but you can put that code into each of the parsers (or handlers, if you prefer).  So instead of returning, you set the variable in the parse (or handle) method.

Comment: @JimmyJames That's where my idea of including an object comes in. In one case, you're updating the object.dob, in another case you're updating object.gender. You would then later use object.dob (or object.getDob()) where you had been using dob. One key aspect is to generate an "object" that matches your domain. The object could be "Customer" or "JobApplication" (whatever you're actually creating). Later in the program, you may call if(JobApplication.getApplicant().getDob() > 21).

Comment: @JimmyJames isn't that just moving the problem again? I'm still going to have to find the line parser type which returns the gender from the list of line parsers and then extract it from a property in that class?

Comment: @LeviH I've update the code a bit.  Let me know if it addresses your concern.

Comment: Not sure why this answer has been upvoted. It's taken a simple but long winded piece of code and has increased both its size and complexity by spreading that functionality out across a number of highly repetitive classes. This is a dreadful solution in my view.

Answer (score 3):

## Use a list of delegates

...to call idemopotent parsing functions encapsulated in an injectable class contained in an extesnsible object model

I'm going to introduce a few programming concepts here so bear with the long answer. This may seem overcomplicated until you're used to it. But all of these patterns are actually very common and very useful in commercial software.

### Create a DTO

First, you need somewhere to store your results all together. A DTO class perhaps; would look like this example. I added a `ToString()` override so you can see the contents in the debug pane instead of just the class name:

```
public enum Gender
{
    Male, Female
}

public class DocumentMetadata
{
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public string RefNum { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("DocumentMetadata: DOB={0:yyyy-MM-dd}, Gender={1}, RefNum={2}", DateOfBirth, Gender, RefNum);
    }
}
```

### Define a delegate for parser methods that follow a pattern

Now that we have a DTO, we can reason about how to parse the lines. Ideally, we'd want a series of idempotent functions that you can unit test easily. And to iterate over them, it would be helpful if they were similar in some way. So we define a delegate:

```
public delegate bool Parser(string line, DocumentMetadata dto);
```

So we can write a parser method sort of like this:

```
protected bool ParseDateOfBirth(string line, DocumentMetadata dto)
{
    if (!line.StartsWith("DOB:")) return false;
    dto.DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse(line.Substring(4));
    return true;
}
```

We can write any number of parser methods, and as long as they return a boolean and accept a string and a DTO object as arguments, they will all match the delegate, so they could all be put into a list, sort of like this:

```
List<Parser>  parsers = new List<Parser>
{
    ParseDateOfBirth,
    ParseGender,
    ParseRefNum
};
```

We'll use this capability in a moment when we write the parser class.

### Create the base parser class

Now here are a few more things to worry about:

1. We want our parser methods contained in a single unit of code, e.g. a class.
2. We want the class to be injectable, e.g. in case you need to have more than one kind of parser in the future, and so you can stub it out for unit tests.
3. We want the logic for iterating parsers to be common.

So first define an interface:

```
public interface IDocumentParser
{
    DocumentMetadata Parse(IEnumerable<string> input);
}
```

An abstract base parser:

```
public abstract class BaseParser : IDocumentParser
{
    protected abstract List<Parser> GetParsers();

    public virtual DocumentMetadata Parse(IEnumerable<string> input)
    {
        var parsers = this.GetParsers();
        var instance = new DocumentMetadata();

        foreach (var line in input)
        {
            foreach (var parser in parsers)
            {
                parser(line, instance);  //This is the line that does it all!!!
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }       
}
```

Or if we want the Parse function to be a bit more clever (and also count the lines that are successfully parsed):

```
    public virtual DocumentMetadata Parse(IEnumerable<string> input)
    {
        var parsers = this.GetParsers();
        var instance = new DocumentMetadata();

        var successCount = input.Sum( line => parsers.Count( parser => parser(line, instance) ));

        Console.WriteLine("{0} lines successfully parsed.", successCount);

        return instance;
    }
```

While the LINQ solution is more "clever" the nested loops may communicate the intent more clearly. Judgment call here. I like the LINQ version because I can count the lines that succeed, and possibly use that information to validate the document.

### Implement the parsers

Now we have a basic framework for parsing documents. All we need is to implement `GetParsers` so that it returns a list of methods that do the work:

```
public class DocumentParser : BaseParser
{
    protected override List<Parser> GetParsers()
    {
        return new List<Parser>
        {
            ParseDateOfBirth,
            ParseGender,
            ParseRefNum
        };
    }

    private bool ParseDateOfBirth(string line, DocumentMetadata dto)
    {
       ///Implementation
    }

    private bool ParseGender(string line, DocumentMetadata dto)
    {
       ///Implementation        
    }

    private bool ParseRefNum(string line, DocumentMetadata dto)
    {
       ///Implementation
    }
}
```

Notice that only the document-specific logic is held in the final implementation. And all it does is supply the delegates via `GetParsers()`. All common logic is in the base class, where it can be reused.

### Test

We can now parse a document with a couple lines of code:

```
var parser = new DocumentParser();
var doc = parse.Parse(input);
```

But we'd like to inject this thing, so let's write it properly:

```
public class Application
{
    protected readonly IDocumentParser _parser; // injected

    public Application(IDocumentParser parser)
    {
        _parser = parser;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        var input = new string[]
        {
            "DOB:1/1/2018",
            "Sex:Male",
            "RefNum:1234"
        };

        var result = _parser.Parse(input);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var application = new Application(new DocumentParser());
        application.Run();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3 lines successfully parsed.
DocumentMetadata: DOB=2018-01-01, Gender=Male, RefNum=1234
```

Now we have all of the following:

1. Generic logic for iterating over all the parsers
2. An extensible object model allowing new parsers to be introduced
3. An injectable interface
4. Idemopotent, unit-testable methods that do the complicated stuff
5. The ability to count successful parse operations (which could be used, for example, to ensure the document is valid)
6. A class that encapsulates the resulting data

[Working example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nWt5Yi)

Answer (score 1):

## Answer to your Question

A more C#-esque solution would be to take advantage of delegates:

```
delegate bool TryParseHandler(string line);

private readonly TryParseHandler[] _handlers = new[]
{
    TryParseDob,
    TryParseGender,
    TryParseRefNumber,
    //...
}
bool TryParseDob(string line)
{
    if(!IsDob(line)) return false;
    dob = ParseDob(line);
    return true;
}
//etc
void ProcessLine(string line)
{
    foreach(var handler in _handlers)
    {
        if(handler(line)) return;
    }
}
```

## Answer to your Problem

The correct answer would be to ditch your "is" solution entirely. What does "line" look like? Is it regular? Does it contain keywords? For example, does it look like `dob: 1/1/1990`, `gender: female`, `ref: 123456`? If so, you want to pull out those keywords and use that for your lookup:

```
private readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, Action<string>> _setValueLookup = new Dictionary<string, Action<string>>
{
    ["dob"] = s => dob = DateTime.Parse(s),
    ["gender"] = s => gender = ParseGender(s),
    ["ref"] = s => refString = s,
};
void ProcessLine(string line)
{
    var pair = line.Split(new []{':'}, 2);
    if(pair.Length < 2) 
    {
        unknownLines.Add(line);
        return;
    }

    var key = pair[0];
    var value = pair[1];
    if(!_setValueLookup.TryGetValue(key, out Action<string> callback))
    {
        unknownLines.Add(line);
        return;
    }

    callback(value);
}
```

Comment: Not a fan of the "answer to your question". `if(handler(line)) return;` isn't really intuitive for a consumer of the underlying logic. There is also an inherent danger about conflicting lines (e.g. ones that match multiple criteria), but the proposed separate delegates make it less than easy to spot/maintain (compared to the `if else` example. It definitely has its issues, but it keeps the order of execution a bit more readable). Big fan of the "answer to your problem"; but I'd extend it further. Instead of assuming every line has the same structure, you could [..]

Comment: [..] use a Func/Action here too, essentially pairing a `Func<string,bool>` (does the line match the condition?) and an `Action<string>` (then take this action). This makes the answer more universally applicable in cases where not every line is expected to begin with a predefined keyword.

Answer (score -1):

If you are happy using lambdas and linq, you can simplify all of that code as:

```
var lineHandlers = new List<(Func<LineType, bool> test, Action<LineType> action)>
{
    (IsDob, l => dob = ParseDob()),
    (IsGender, l => gender = ParseGender(l)),
    (IsRefNumber, l => refNumber = ParseRefNumber(l)),
    (_ => true, l => unknownLines.Add(l))
};

var (_, action) = lineHandlers.First(handler => handler.test(line));
action(line);
```

(Note, requires C# 7 in order to use tuples. Just replace that tuple with a simple type if you are using an old version of the compiler).

Comment: This is a dreadful solution in my view.

Comment: @JimmyJames, come on, you can do better than that. At least I gave you the courtesy of explaining why yours was a dreadful solution. You appear to have just retaliated in a temper tantrum :)

Comment: I typically don't comment on other people's answers in order to criticize them (or the people who upvoted them) because it seems quite childish to me.  There are exceptions, however.  This approach is poor (IMO) because you've done nothing to address the concerns of the OP, you've simply made it more terse and less understandable.